# I want to make pallet to transfer NFTs between different chains through xcm?

Tags: xcm, nft

I want to transfer NFTs between a relay chain and a parachain. Does anyone have any knowledge or ideas about how to accomplish this

Answer (score 1):

There was a PR regarding supporting non-fungibles [here](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/pull/4950).

And there are also some nice examples in the XCM Simulator:

```rust
/// Scenario:
/// The relay-chain teleports an NFT to a parachain.
///
/// Asserts that the parachain accounts are updated as expected.
#[test]
fn teleport_nft() {
    MockNet::reset();

    Relay::execute_with(|| {
        // Mint the NFT (1, 69) and give it to our "parachain#1 alias".
        assert_ok!(relay_chain::Uniques::mint(
            relay_chain::RuntimeOrigin::signed(ALICE),
            1,
            69,
            child_account_account_id(1, ALICE),
        ));
        // The parachain#1 alias of Alice is what must hold it on the Relay-chain for it to be
        // withdrawable by Alice on the parachain.
        assert_eq!(
            relay_chain::Uniques::owner(1, 69),
            Some(child_account_account_id(1, ALICE))
        );
    });
    ParaA::execute_with(|| {
        assert_ok!(parachain::ForeignUniques::force_create(
            parachain::RuntimeOrigin::root(),
            (Parent, GeneralIndex(1)).into(),
            ALICE,
            false,
        ));
        assert_eq!(
            parachain::ForeignUniques::owner((Parent, GeneralIndex(1)).into(), 69u32.into()),
            None,
        );
        assert_eq!(parachain::Balances::reserved_balance(&ALICE), 0);

        // IRL Alice would probably just execute this locally on the Relay-chain, but we can't
        // easily do that here since we only send between chains.
        let message = Xcm(vec![
            WithdrawAsset((GeneralIndex(1), 69u32).into()),
            InitiateTeleport {
                assets: AllCounted(1).into(),
                dest: Parachain(1).into(),
                xcm: Xcm(vec![DepositAsset {
                    assets: AllCounted(1).into(),
                    beneficiary: (AccountId32 { id: ALICE.into(), network: None },).into(),
                }]),
            },
        ]);
        // Send teleport
        let alice = AccountId32 { id: ALICE.into(), network: None };
        assert_ok!(ParachainPalletXcm::send_xcm(alice, Parent, message));
    });
    ParaA::execute_with(|| {
        assert_eq!(
            parachain::ForeignUniques::owner((Parent, GeneralIndex(1)).into(), 69u32.into()),
            Some(ALICE),
        );
        assert_eq!(parachain::Balances::reserved_balance(&ALICE), 1000);
    });
    Relay::execute_with(|| {
        assert_eq!(relay_chain::Uniques::owner(1, 69), None);
    });
}

/// Scenario:
/// The relay-chain transfers an NFT into a parachain's sovereign account, who then mints a
/// trustless-backed-derivated locally.
///
/// Asserts that the parachain accounts are updated as expected.
#[test]
fn reserve_asset_transfer_nft() {
    sp_tracing::init_for_tests();
    MockNet::reset();

    Relay::execute_with(|| {
        assert_ok!(relay_chain::Uniques::force_create(
            relay_chain::RuntimeOrigin::root(),
            2,
            ALICE,
            false
        ));
        assert_ok!(relay_chain::Uniques::mint(
            relay_chain::RuntimeOrigin::signed(ALICE),
            2,
            69,
            child_account_account_id(1, ALICE)
        ));
        assert_eq!(
            relay_chain::Uniques::owner(2, 69),
            Some(child_account_account_id(1, ALICE))
        );
    });
    ParaA::execute_with(|| {
        assert_ok!(parachain::ForeignUniques::force_create(
            parachain::RuntimeOrigin::root(),
            (Parent, GeneralIndex(2)).into(),
            ALICE,
            false,
        ));
        assert_eq!(
            parachain::ForeignUniques::owner((Parent, GeneralIndex(2)).into(), 69u32.into()),
            None,
        );
        assert_eq!(parachain::Balances::reserved_balance(&ALICE), 0);

        let message = Xcm(vec![
            WithdrawAsset((GeneralIndex(2), 69u32).into()),
            DepositReserveAsset {
                assets: AllCounted(1).into(),
                dest: Parachain(1).into(),
                xcm: Xcm(vec![DepositAsset {
                    assets: AllCounted(1).into(),
                    beneficiary: (AccountId32 { id: ALICE.into(), network: None },).into(),
                }]),
            },
        ]);
        // Send transfer
        let alice = AccountId32 { id: ALICE.into(), network: None };
        assert_ok!(ParachainPalletXcm::send_xcm(alice, Parent, message));
    });
    ParaA::execute_with(|| {
        log::debug!(target: "xcm-exceutor", "Hello");
        assert_eq!(
            parachain::ForeignUniques::owner((Parent, GeneralIndex(2)).into(), 69u32.into()),
            Some(ALICE),
        );
        assert_eq!(parachain::Balances::reserved_balance(&ALICE), 1000);
    });

    Relay::execute_with(|| {
        assert_eq!(relay_chain::Uniques::owner(2, 69), Some(child_account_id(1)));
    });
}
```

- https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/60af0cab8bbfe3fb23d605b296acd60030e25504/xcm/xcm-simulator/example/src/lib.rs#L359-L492

There was also some discussion in the Polkadot Forum:

- https://forum.polkadot.network/t/cross-chain-nft-transfer